# Maximum Principle for the PDE $\Delta u - a^2u=a^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I have this Dirichlet probem

\begin{align*}
\Delta u - a^2u&=a^2\quad\text{on}\;\, \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n \\
u&\equiv 0\quad \, \text{ on }\partial \Omega,
\end{align*}
where $a^2$ is constant and $a^2>0$.

And the book says, **"by the maximum principle implies $u>-1$"**

I know this about the maximum principle: it says that the maximum of a function in a domain is to be found on the boundary of that domain.

But I dont understand why $u> -1$.

I try this.

$$ \dfrac{\Delta u }{a^2} - u = 1 \\
\Rightarrow u = \dfrac{\Delta u }{a^2} -1 ...$$

Comment: Let $Lw=\Delta w - a^2w $ and let $u $ solve your problem.Let $v=u+1$. Then $Lv=Lu-a^2=0$. Now try to show $v>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the hint by Ian, let $v=u+1$. The function $v$ satisfies the PDE $\Delta v=v$, and is positive on the boundary of $\Omega$. So, if $v$ was negative somewhere, its (negative) global minimum would be attained in the interior... but the Laplacian can't be negative at an interior minimum.